# How to iterate extra fields in a webform component

Tags: 7, webforms

When I select the extra field of a webform component:

```
$webform_components = db_select('webform_component', 'c')
                          ->fields('c', array('type', 'form_key', 'extra'))
                          ->condition('nid', $nid)
                          ->execute()
                          ->fetchAll();
```

The extra field is something like this (the following example is a grid component):

```
"a:8:{s:13:\"title_display\";s:4:\"none\";s:7:\"private\";i:0;s:15:\"wrapper_classes\";s:0:\"\";s:6:\"sticky\";i:1;s:7:\"options\";s:20:\"5|poor\n10|excellent\n\";s:18:\"custom_option_keys\";i:1;s:9:\"questions\";s:159:\"mensaje|Each message is associated with a language, which may or may not be the\nactual|current user's selected language, depending on the type of e-mail being\n\";s:20:\"custom_question_keys\";i:1;}"
```

I want to get the options and the questions. In the previous example:

```
\"options\";s:20:\"5|poor\n10|excellent\
```

**Option 1**: 5 (key) | poor (value)

**Option 2**: 10 (key) | excellent (value)

```
\"questions\";s:159:\"mensaje|Each message is associated with a language, which may or may not be the\nactual|current user's selected language, depending on the type of e-mail being
```

**Question 1**: mensaje (key) | Each message [...] (value)

**Question 2**: actual (key)| current user's [...] (value)

I don't know how to process this *extra* string. I tried to transform it to an array and a json, but it didn't work.

Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a serialised PHP string, so:

```
$unserialised = unserialize($input);

// Split $unserialised['options'] by the '|' char, then extract keys/values
```

Comment: I love you so much! :* I didn't know this string type. BTW, there is a typo in the function name, is unseriali**z**e (I'm newbie, sorry I cannot edit automatically your answer).

Comment: Happy to help :) Sorry 'bout the typo (the pains of speaking British English and using a language predominantly written by American English speakers!) I've fixed that now